# Unity: критично ли создание обилия пустых объектов?

Tags: unity3d, объекты, оптимизация

Как-то на видео человек использовал пустые объекты как разделители или папки. В ui рекомендовалось не делать их, поэтому решил спросить: пустые объекты как вложенность и разделители дают нагрузку или использовать их только по крайней необходимости?

Comment: Не рекомендовалось кем? Откуда ты это взял?

Comment: "обилие пустых объектов"  это когда тысячи, а когда у тебя там три допника сверху - это ни на что не повлияет

Comment: Yaroslav, "Оптимизация ui"